# Integrate an existing application in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I have a completely developed application in drupal. I need to setup it in my local environment.
I have downloaded all the required drupal configuration including database, wamp server

Is there a way to integrate existing application with drupal.

Also, Do we need an IDE to run the application in Drupal.

Where to host the database??

Comment: If you run the wamp server, you can host your databse in your phpmyadmin environment. You want to run a Drupal site in your browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Download wamp server and install it after www folder by default create in c folder. put your drupal application in www folder and in wamp server phpmyadmin there put your database in it for that create new databse after import option use for import database .set database name and password in site/all/default/setting.php  online number 220.after that in browser loalhost/your drupal site name.